# Does there exist a bounded function of class $C^{\infty}$ such that all of its derivatives at $0$ coincide with the derivatives of $e^{-x} +x+1$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider the function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $g(x) = e^{-x} + x + 1$.

Does there exist a bounded function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ of class $C^{\infty}$ such that $f^{(n)}(0) = g^{(n)}(0)$ for all $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$?

Here, $f^{(n)}(x)$ denotes the nth derivative of $f$ at $x$, and $f^{(0)}(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with partitions of unity? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity)

Comment: @Blumenthal Type this [this]${}$(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity) in order to get [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity)

Comment: @ABlumenthal Nope. I've never seen that before. Does that offer an immediate answer to this?

Comment: It should be as simple as adding smooth bump functions to $e^{-x}+x+1$.

Comment: @JSchlather Is that a simple thing to do? Is the [Whitney extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem) an overkill?

Comment: @GitGud It is a simpler thing than partition of unity: $$f(x)=e^{-x}+x+1+\chi_{\{x>1\}}e^{-1/(x-1)^2}$$  (not a bump function, as we have  no requirement to  truncate the support of the added term).

Comment: @5pm I don't get what $\chi$ is supposed to mean.

Comment: @GitGud [Characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function), also denoted as $1_{\{x>1\}}$ and $[x>1]$, the latter being [Iverson bracket notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Just a formal way of saying: last term is added only when $x>1$.

Comment: @5pm You have to work a little harder than that because he wants it bounded. But multiplication works just fine as in A Walkers answer.

Comment: @JSchlather I see: I misread the problem and thought that $f-g$ was meant to be bounded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function that is identically $1$ on a neighborhood of $0$, and has compact support.  Look into [bump functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) for more on this.
Then $fg = g$ on a neighborhood of $0$, so that $(fg)^{(n)}=g^{(n)}$ as desired.  But $fg$ has compact support, so it is bounded.

The existence of bump functions is one of the more significant differences between smooth and analytic/real analytic functions.

Comment: All right. I'll trust you and Wikipedia on the existence of this bump function. Can you name a course in which I can learn these things in detail? Thanks!

Comment: @TuringMachine Bump functions pop up in lots of places. I first learned up about them from a course in smooth manifolds. They also come up lots in PDE and most advanced analysis courses.

Comment: @TuringMachine It's easy (at least in $\mathbb{R}$) to get bump functions.  Let $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x >0$ and $f=0$ for $x\leq 0$.  Claim: $f$ is smooth.  Now look at $h(x)=f(x)f(1-x)$, which is smooth and supported in $[0,1]$.  Now integrate to get a smooth CDF, which equals $0$ on $x<0$ and constant for $x>1$.  Normalize to get $h(x)=1$ for $x>1$.  Let $j=h(x)h(3-x)$.  This is smooth, supported in $[0,3]$, and satisfies $j=1$ on $(1,2)$.  Hope this helps!  (For $\mathbb{R}^n$, consider rotating $j$ about an axis.)

Comment: Hm, I see. Looks like one of those things which you practice for some time and it then becomes "second nature". I'll look more into that some day. Thanks for the help!